# Is there any way to change the type of the variable before initialization can you explain with an example?

Tags: c++

```
int element;                
(float)element;
cout << typeid(element).name() << endl;
```

Comment: Hello to stack overflow (SO). 
We here at SO are eager to you, but please play along our rules, to make it easier for us. 
Consider reading through the [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and 
taking the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Especially consider reading through 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can't change the type of a variable.

Comment: @Scheff - That's not a comment, that's (quite a good) answer.

Comment: @MartinBonner There are people which don't like to answer questions of low quality (lacking research). That's why I didn't dare to write an answer but I felt able to provide a little bit help. However, I know also that other people don't like answers in comments. ;-)

Comment: I sense an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 3):

Concerning:

```
int element;                
(float)element;
cout << typeid(element).name() << endl;
```

`int element;` tells the compiler to allocated storage with `sizeof (int)` (and associated it with symbol `element`).

Additionally, it remembers the type (at compile time) for further usages of the variable (as expression).

`(float)element;` tells the compiler to access variable `element` (it's of type `int`) and convert its value to `float` (without further processing). This is a conversion of the temporary value read from `element` not `element`s storage or type. – `element` is still of type `int`.

---

To answer (part of) the question

> Is there any way to change the type of the variable

No. It's not allowed to change the type of the variable this way.

Concerning the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (suspected by molbdnilo):

It is possible to provide storage for a variable "on demand" (at runtime) using dynamic allocation with [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new). Though, using `new` directly is actually discouraged. Allocating something with `new` should also `delete` it later when memory is not needed anymore. Handling the `delete` correctly (double `delete`ing something is prohibited but not `delete`ing something causes a memory-leak), is not that easy to maintain.

Please, note that local variables (if not declared `static` or `extern`) have a life-time which starts not before scope is entered and ends when scope is left. Hence, it's questionable whether shared storage for alternative types is worth at all. Instead, just the respective number of alternative local variables could be used.

However, it is possible to provide a variable with possible alternative types (where only one is used at at time) with a [`union`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) or a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (since C++17).

A sample for `std::variant`:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

typedef std::variant<int, float> IntOrFloat;

void print(IntOrFloat value)
{
  std::cout << "value: ";
  if (std::holds_alternative<int>(value)) {
    std::cout << std::get<int>(value) << " (int)\n";
  } else if (std::holds_alternative<float>(value)) {
    std::cout << std::get<float>(value) << " (float)\n";
  }
}

int main()
{
  IntOrFloat value = 123; // now it's an int
  print(value);
  value = 1.23f; // now it's a float
  print(value);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
value: 123 (int)
value: 1.23 (float)
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0ce3b916a074a5e)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for answering my question @ Scheff. Actually This is my first question in stack Overflow. From next time on wards I will definitely provide more detailed information . Thank you so much for taking time to answer the question.